# Is there a way to fix an xcframework so it works on M1 and Intel simulators?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-silicon, xcframework

Edit: Selecting Xcode in Finder, getting info, and ticking the box for `Open using Rosetta` makes things work, but surely there is a better way…

I have an iOS project with a static framework containing three variants in it; `ios-armv7_armv7s_arm64`, `ios-i386_x86_64-simulator`, and `ios-x86_64-maccatalyst`. I do not have any access to the source code for this framework and asking for a new build of the framework is not a practical option. As a result I need to work with the `xcframework` that I have in hand.

The framework works just fine on my colleagues machines as they are using Intel based Macs. As a new addition to the team I have been given an M1 machine. While I can build to a physical device, building to the simulator fails with missing symbols. This makes complete sense given that the simulator variant doesn't have arm64 in it.

Simply adding a new definition to the `info.plist` to cover the M1 chip doesn't work as that means there are two simulator definitions. (There are also other issues with this route)

If I duplicate the `ios-armv7_armv7s_arm64` folder, add `-simulator` to the copies name, and replace the existing definition for the simulator framework with info from the `ios-armv7_armv7s_arm64` definition I get an error about building for the simulator but linking in a file built for iOS. This means that no matter what I can't simply copy the existing M1 framework to get things going.

The only things I can think of both involve the need to somehow edit the M1 copy of the compiled framework so that it will work on the simulator, and I rather doubt there is a way to do that. If it is possible to do though I would then need to either come up with some nested framework trick that allowed me to have two definitions for the simulator but for two different architectures; or I would need to write a script that used `uname -m` to decide how to edit the framework's `info.plist` file (This feels very hacky, but would be the simplest way of making the project 'just work' on both Intel and M1 machines without the need to make manual adjustments and remember not to commit them.

Anyone have any brilliant ideas on how to get this framework working in the simulator without having a new copy built? (I haven't even found a clear method for how it would need to be built to work on both architectures.)

Xcode: 13.3.1

Comment: It isn't t possible for it to "just work" without rebuilding the framework to include both x86 and Arm64 simulator slices. Rather than running Xcode under Rosetta you can go the the architectures section of your Xcode project and for debug add a line for "any IOS simulator SDK" with the value "x86".  Now your Xcode runs in m1 but you will use x86 simulators

Comment: Thanks that makes it a little better. I thought about going to the simulator app itself and just setting that to run with Rosetta. This looks like a better per project setting that can then carry into the repo and save others from dealing with it.